# hibernate. many-to-many. bidirectional association. What does mean the owner?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I know that in  many-to-many bidirectional association are owner and dependent entity.
What do I know about owner and dependent for writing my application?
What differencies are between them?

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqi):

> The direction of a relationship can be either bidirectional or unidirectional. A bidirectional relationship has both an owning side and an inverse side. A unidirectional relationship has only an owning side. **The owning side of a relationship determines how the Persistence runtime makes updates to the relationship in the database**.

I think about about owning side as "main" side of the relation. Entity on this side defines most of the properties of the relation and it's state is used to "control" relation.

Comment: "owning side as "main" side of the relation" - what is mean?

Comment: @user2765953 as I've said: [1] owning side defines most of the relation configuration (for example specifies `@JoinColumn` annotation to override join column name), [2] when persisting, state of the owning side entity (and not of the inverse side entity) is used to update relations.

Comment: For example  I have many to many relation between A a and B b. Exist differrencies for update entities(a or b, without cascades) that note add in A_B table ?